# How to filter(contains particular string) list of key objects (s3) into a new list

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, arraylist, java-stream

I am trying to filter out from list of key objects taking from s3 containing particular string.
this is my method:

```
public List<String>getBucketList3(String filterStr) {

        List<String> lst = new ArrayList<>();

        ListObjectsRequest listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest()
                .withBucketName(bucketName);
        ObjectListing objectListing = s3client.listObjects(listObjectsRequest);
        for (; ; ) {
            List<S3ObjectSummary> summaries = objectListing.getObjectSummaries();
            if (summaries.size() < 1) {
                break;
            }
            summaries.forEach(s -> lst.add(s.getKey()));
            objectListing = s3client.listNextBatchOfObjects(objectListing);
        }

        return lst;
    }
```

I am trying to filter out only key objects which contains 'filterStr' and add it to my 'lst' array list string.
I am trying to use stream() of java 8 in order to accomplish it, but I am struggling resolving it.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> list = lst.stream()
        .filter(s -> s.contains(filterStr))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It could work like that, if that is the right predicate for your case.

Comment: I am filtering summeries list which is: List<S3ObjectSummary> list type...
I want to get all keys matches my string filter (filterStr) and add this key to my list (lst) which is List<String> type.

Comment: You can adopt this to your list.
Instead of List<String> use List<S3ObjectSummary>.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
ObjectListing objectListing = s3client.listObjects(listObjectsRequest);
List<S3ObjectSummary> summaries = objectListing.getObjectSummaries();
List<String> lst = new ArrayList<>();
do {
    lst.addAll(summaries.stream()
            .map(S3ObjectSummary::getKey) // creates a string stream
            .filter(s -> s.contains(filterStr)) // filters all values containing filterStr
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    objectListing = s3client.listNextBatchOfObjects(objectListing);
    summaries = objectListing.getObjectSummaries();
} while (!summaries.isEmpty());
```